# VBA to move cell selection

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA to move the cell selection down one row/cell in column E everytime cell A6 changes. please help! thank you!

I already have a VBA code to keep a cell selection in the same cell if A5 changes. is it possible to have two of these VBA change codes in the same sheet?

Comment: If you include your existing code into the question, it will make it much, much easier for someone to show you how to amend it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes. You just need to add criteria on which change event to capture. For example, something like below will work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo forward
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.[A5]) Is Nothing Then
        '/* your code to keep selection */
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.[A6]) Is Nothing Then
        '/* your code to move cell selection down */
    End If

forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```